sheet.getRange("A1").activate() not working
I have text in cell E9.  I want to have the text and color change and code execute when click on cell.  I have not put any code in yet, just testing for now.I have the following script which should change the text and color in cell E9 when clicked, and then move the cursor to cell A1:
function onSelectionChange(e) {
   const range = e.range;
   const sheet = range.getSheet();
   const a1Notation = range.getA1Notation();
   if (a1Notation == "E9") {
     if (range.getValue() == "SHOW Guidelines") {
       range.setBackground("#ff0000");
       range.setValue("HIDE Guidelines");
       } else {
       range.setBackground("#38761d");
       range.setValue("SHOW Guidelines");
       }
        }
     sheet.getRange("A1").activate();
     console.log("test2")    
         }

When I click on cell E9, the value of the cell changes with the color, as it should.  The execution log shows "test2",so I now it executed past the prior line, but the active cell is still E9 (it did not move to A1 as would be expected). Is there something I am missing?  Or any suggestions on another method?

Using: Windows 11, tried in both Chrome and Edge and with all extensions disabled.
So here is what I have done.
First, changed code to this:
 function onSelectionChange(e) {
  const range = e.range;
  const sheet  = range.getSheet();
  
  console.log("before activate")
  sheet.getRange("A1").activate();
  console.log("after activate")
}

Next, goto spreadsheet, refresh it, click a few cells, nothing moves to A1.
Check logs, all show before and after activate.
Open new blank spreadsheet, add the above code, refresh spreadsheet and test.
Click 1 or 2 cells, moves to A1 and logs show before and after activate.
Next copy entire script from 1st spreadsheet and put in this new one.
Now goto new spreadsheet, refresh and click 1 or 2 cells.
Now nothing moves to A1 when click on any cell, and logs still show the before and after activate.
So deleted ALL code EXCEPT the original code above.
Go to spreadsheet, refresh, click 1 or 2 cells, nothing moves to A1, but logs still show before and after activate.
Then just to see, changed onSelectionChange to onEdit.
Went to spreadsheet, typed something arbitrary into a cell, and the cursor moved to A1.
So went back, changed back to onSelectionChange and does not move to A1.
Completely deleted and saved.
Went back again, put code above in, and tried it.  Does not work.
So the only thing that I can think of is that something in the original code is causing it.
But what I can't figure out is why it worked on new spreadheet, but even after copy/paste caused it not to work, why deleting and starting over with new code it still does not work.
Did original code cause something that can't be removed?
At a total loss since it works when put just the code above alone in.
But when put original code it doesn't work.
And when I remove all original code leaving just the code above, still doesn't work.
Not sure what else it could be.

Generally I have to reload the container whenever I create an onSelectionChange trigger

Hi! Your code works for me as well. I am not encountering any issues with the background color change and cursor selection change part of your code. If this issue persists I would recommend providing a gif on how you conduct this test. This might answer @Wicket's questions.

Which browser or app?

This works  for me:
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  e.source.toast("Entry");
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Sheet0" && e.range.columnStart == 5 && e.range.rowStart == 9) {
    e.source.toast("gate1");
    if (e.value == "SHOW Guidelines") {
      e.range.setBackground("#ff0000");
      e.range.setValue("HIDE Guidelines");
    } else {
      e.range.setBackground("#38761d");
      e.range.setValue("SHOW Guidelines");
    }
    sh.getRange("A1").activate();
  }
}


This did not work at all.  Clicking cell E9 does nothing.  And checking execution log I get the following (subsituted xxx for the email and nickname):
Jun 10, 2024, 7:53:48 PM Info {"range":{"columnEnd":5,"columnStart":5,"rowEnd":9,"rowStart":9},"authMode":"LIMITED","source":{},"user":{"email":"xxxxxx@gmail.com","nickname":"xxxxxx"}}

Are the toasts working for you?

Your code works for me. I wonder what exact steps you follow for testing the onSelectionChange.
I made a slight change to make the function runnable from the code editor: I added a default object, including the source and range properties. On this function, only range is needed.
function onSelectionChange(
  e = {
    source: SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
    range: SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange()
  }
) {
  const range = e.range;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  const a1Notation = range.getA1Notation();
  if (a1Notation == "E9") {
    if (range.getValue() == "SHOW Guidelines") {
      range.setBackground("#ff0000");
      range.setValue("HIDE Guidelines");
    } else {
      range.setBackground("#38761d");
      range.setValue("SHOW Guidelines");
    }
  }
  sheet.getRange("A1").activate();
  console.log("test2")
}


Please ensure that you have authorized the script. Let's assume that the script requires re-authorization. To reauthorize it, run onSelectionChange from the script editor. If you didn't assign a default object to e, don't worry about the error due to e being undefined.
Just to be super-sure that the Google Sheet web app caught the onSelectionChange, close and reopen the spreadsheet. Then, test again that onSelectionChange works as expected.
If the problem still happens, disable all the add-ons and web browser extensions and try again. You can create a new web browser profile or use your browser in private mode. Please ensure that no extensions are allowed to run in private mode.

Test Steps
Preparation
Before starting this test, please ensure everything is in place and ready to be tested. Verify that your computer operating system and web browser are updated.
It is highly recommended to use the Google Chrome stable channel.
Set your web browser to start showing the default tab.
Turn off your computer.
Seriously, this test should begin by starting your computer, so please turn it off.
Start

Turn on your computer.
Open your web browser.
Go to https://sheets.google.com and look for the spreadsheet containing the onSelectionChange function to test.
Open the spreadsheet. The spreadsheet should be opened showing the first sheet. A1 should be the current cell, active range and selection.

Scenario 1: E9 is blank or the value of E9 is not equal to SHOW Guidelines.

Click on E9. The effect of this is that now E9 is the current cell, active range and selection. Hold any action for a few seconds to give time to the onSelectionChange execution finish.
Once the execution of onSelectionChange finishes, the value of E9 should be SHOW Guidelines, the cell background of E9 should be green (#38761d), and the current cell, active range and selection should be A1.

Scenario 2: The value of E9 is equal to SHOW Guidelines.

Click on E9. The effect of this is that now E9 is the current cell, active range and selection. Hold any action for a few seconds to give time to the onSelectionChange execution finish.
Once the execution of onSelectionChange finishes, the value of E9 should be HIDE Guidelines, the cell background of E9 should be red (#ff0000), and the current cell, active range and selection should be A1.


I have tried everything, each script here, the script is authorized, I have closed the spreadsheet and opened again, and disabled all add-ons.  Even tried with a different browser. No matter what I do, it doesn't run the activate code,. so after clicking the cursor stays at E9.  The only way to get it to work is to click a different cell, then click E9 again.  I know the code is right, but it just doesn't want to work for me.

I even tried changing the activate line to "var result = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("did it", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL); to get a popup and the execution log shows it times out.

@Doc It looks like there is something that you still need to tell us about your environment (spreadsheet, contained script, etc.). Start from scratch: Create a new spreadsheet, click Extensions > Apps Script, add the onSelectionChange function and nothing more. Authorize the script and do your test steps. Please ensure to take detailed notes.
